# mimic swagger api on spring boot application

Tags: spring, swagger

I got a Spring boot REST based proxy server application with standard REST End point exposed(GET, POST,PUT and DELETE) to outside world.

Any requests coming from external world then will be routed to actual functionality internally.

Now the requirement is to expose all the API supported by my REST proxy server. As I mentioned I do not have static controller path in my code for individual APIs. So would like to get your input how to create swagger support for all the internal APIs that my proxy server support. Is there are a way I can generate swagger schema manually to mimics the controller path? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for creating swagger API link will be helpful to you http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Thanks @KalaiselvanA . In my case I do not have static controller path to generate swagger. I was wondering, is there a way I can generate Swagger APIs without having actual Controller Path in the code(from generic REST end points)

Comment: Which means without having controller class or what? or class doesn't contain `@RestController` @Ajay Gopu

Comment: @KalaiselvanA - My REST server is acting as a Proxy server. One work around I could do is, generate Swagger yaml / json from the actual server where I have all my controller paths are defined. Change the host ip address in generated swagger schema to my proxy server. And bring a swagger ui which will display the api document from the generate swagger schema / yml/ json file. It works, but if you know any better solution, please let me know.